# Is this kernel warning a major problem that needs my attention?

Tags: networking, kernel-modules, tcp, nas

Our Linux based Thecus N12000 NAS recently experienced this message in its `dmesg` log.

```
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]  ------------[ cut here ]------------
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]  WARNING: at net/ipv4/tcp_input.c:2966 tcp_ack+0xd88/0x1a1c()
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]  Hardware name: IRONLAKE & IBEX PEAK Chipset
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]  Modules linked in: nfsd lockd nfs_acl auth_rpcgss sunrpc iscsi_tcp libiscsi_tcp libiscsi scsi_transport_iscsi ntfs ses enclosure usblp usb_storage usbhid xhci_hcd uhci_hcd ehci_hcd usbcore sg be2net tehuti igb ixgbe dca e1000e drm_kms_helper drm video backlight sata_sil24 mpt2sas ahci libahci ata_piix
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]  Pid: 1710, comm: smbd Not tainted 2.6.38 #1
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]  Call Trace:
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff8103118e>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x78/0x8c
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff81391339>] ? tcp_ack+0xd88/0x1a1c
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff81392ca5>] ? tcp_rcv_established+0x780/0x9d1
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff81392d42>] ? tcp_rcv_established+0x81d/0x9d1
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff8139a52d>] ? tcp_v4_do_rcv+0x1a1/0x377
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff8139a52d>] ? tcp_v4_do_rcv+0x1a1/0x377
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff81413149>] ? _raw_spin_lock_bh+0x9/0x1f
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff8135374c>] ? release_sock+0x19/0x103
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff81413149>] ? _raw_spin_lock_bh+0x9/0x1f
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff813537cd>] ? release_sock+0x9a/0x103
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff8138a89a>] ? tcp_recvmsg+0x48f/0x9f5
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff8138c24d>] ? tcp_sendpage+0x595/0x5a7
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff81350048>] ? sock_sendmsg+0xc3/0xe0
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff813a5f60>] ? inet_recvmsg+0x64/0x75
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff8134f84e>] ? sock_sendpage+0x36/0x3d
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff8134f7aa>] ? sock_aio_read+0x126/0x13a
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff810a0f4d>] ? do_sync_read+0xb1/0xea
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff810a1921>] ? vfs_read+0xbd/0x12d
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff810a1a47>] ? sys_read+0x45/0x6e
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]   [<ffffffff810027fb>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[2014-05-21 11:34:56]  ---[ end trace cdaf61db513385a1 ]---
```

In researching this error message I've only [found the following info](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c?id=v3.0.4#n2966):

```
if (WARN_ON(!tp->sacked_out && tp->fackets_out))
    tp->fackets_out = 0;
```

I also found this similar error on the oops.kernel.org site, [WARNING: at net/ipv4/tcp_input.c:2966 tcp_ack+0xdbe/0x1f80](http://oops.kernel.org/oops/warning-at-net-ipv4-tcp_input-c2966-tcp_ack0xdbe-0x1f80/).

Is this just a non-issue warning that we can ignore is is symptomatic of something else that I should be concerned with?

#### Isn't this an appliance?

**NOTE:** Though this is a Linux appliance, of sorts, it's actually based on CentOS. I've brought binaries built on CentOS 5 onto the box from time to time and they've run without issues. Tools such as `df` for example.

```
$ uname -a
Linux tank 2.6.38 #1 SMP Fri Oct 26 14:35:05 CST 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

#### References

- [User's Manual for N12000](http://www.thecus.com/download/manual/AllinOne_User_Manual%20x64v5.7/x64%20UM%20v5.7_EN.pdf)
- [N12000 product pages](http://www.thecus.com/product.php?PROD_ID=44)

Comment: Sounds like more of a vendor question unfortunately.....

Comment: @mdpc - Agreed, but given we have some Kernel "hackers" that come here from time to time I thought I'd ask about this here.

Comment: Suggestion, you might want to include the output of uname -a for reference.

Comment: @mdpc - I've added the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct about the location of the WARN, this code is from the upstream kernel tag `v2.6.38`:

```
net/ipv4/tcp_input.c
2953 static void tcp_fastretrans_alert(struct sock *sk, int pkts_acked, int flag)
2954 {
...
2964         if (WARN_ON(!tp->sacked_out && tp->fackets_out))
2965                 tp->fackets_out = 0;
2966
```

This is discussed [here](http://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg188242.html) and fixed with commit:

```
commit 5b35e1e6e9ca651e6b291c96d1106043c9af314a
Author: Neal Cardwell <ncardwell@google.com>
Date:   Sat Jan 28 17:29:46 2012 +0000

    tcp: fix tcp_trim_head() to adjust segment count with skb MSS
```

The date puts its fix in kernel 3.3. This fix was not backported to Red Hat's EL5 source (I checked the 5.11 kernel 2.6.18-398) so if your NAS is based off CentOS 5 then this is not fixed.

It's worth noting there was never a `2.6.38` released for EL5, so this is not a Red Hat or CentOS kernel. I assume your NAS vendor has taken a later upstream kernel, maybe applied some patches, and provided that kernel in the firmware image of your SAN.

If you want to fix this, you'll probably need to get the source for kernel 3.3 or later, apply your SAN vendor's patches, and build your own kernel. It's probably worth checking if this is fixed in [ELRepo's kernel-lt](http://elrepo.org/linux/kernel/el5/x86_64/RPMS/) which is `3.2.63-1.el5`, that's very close to 3.3. If not, you could use ELRepo's `.config` file and `make oldconfig` on the new kernel source to answer a minimum of questions.

That being said, the big isn't a huge deal anyway. The `WARN` occurs because of an accounting error in TCP. If I understand the patch correctly, the functions which account data transmitted using TCP Segmentation Offloading make some incorrect assumptions, resulting in a garbage number of segments being counted under some conditions. The `WARN` fixes this by returning one of the segment counts to 0. I *think* the worst that can happen is that a little more data than necessary is retransmitted when there is packet loss.

You may be able to work around this by disabling TSO. Check you are using TSO with:

```
ethtool -g ethX
```

If so, disable it with:

```
ethtool -G ethX tso off
```

If that works, and your networking is controlled by the regular CentOS initscripts (`/etc/init.d/network` and friends) then you can write `/sbin/ifup-local` to have the change apply every time the interface starts, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 == "ethX" ]]; then
  /sbin/ethtool -G $1 tso off
fi
```

Replace `ethX` with the name of your network interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is an error in the networking code path and has no relation to hardware issue by itself. I doubt you have much of a concern there with regard to the device itself. You can check if you have network packet drops that may cause a problem using ethtool -S and on the other network devices just in case.

It is possible that you have some network issue or that the kernel just got confused about some TCP traffic.